# Many to Many relations in Sails.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

I'm having some troubles with my sails project. I can create students and courses but I'm having trouble getting the relationship to work between them.
I don't really understand how to use the shortcuts to create a student from the URL and have it take one or more courses.

I can create a student easily with: `/student/create?=username=mingzi`. But I can't do something like `/student/create?=username=mingzi&courses=Databases101`

```
//A student can have take many courses
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    username :{
      type: "string",
      required : true
    },
    //reference to courses
    courses: {
      collection: 'Course',
      via: "students"
    },
  }

};

//a course can have many students who takes it 
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    code:{
      type: "string"
    },
    name:{
      type:"string"
    },
    students:{
      collection: "student",
      via: "courses"
    },
  }
};
```

And here's my StudentController.js

```
module.exports = {
    'new':function(req,res){
    res.view();
  }
};
```

And my code for new student:

```
<form action="/student/create" method="POST">
  <h2>Create student</h2>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username"name="username"><br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Courses" name="courses"><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Create Student"/>
</form>
```

Now I can create new students , but I can't get them to have courses and vice versa. How do I do this?

I have all this running to a MySQL database. And it seems to work fine with updating tables and everything when I create a new student or course.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the response and error if you send `/student/create?=username=mingzi&courses=Databases101`? It depends on your blueprints but I guess you need to pass an array as courses and not a single value since it's a Many-to-Many relationship.

Comment: @jelhan I get a basic `500 internal error.  [Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] `